# Strength training and BMR correlation?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, strength-training

Is there an observed or measured correlation between BMR and strength training? (Maybe in a form of x-y graph)

Or muscle weight VS BMR would be useful as well.

I'm not even a beginner at strength training. I'm just trying to lose weight and currently doing cardio everyday for 30mins.

My goal is here to understand how much advantage strength training have for my goal, and adjust my plan accordingly. Frankly, I want to be able to eat more while losing weight by increasing my BMR :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as close as I know of, from a [2001 study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11283427).

> When all subjects were pooled together, absolute RMR significantly
>   increased by 7% (5928 +/- 1225 vs 6328 +/- 1336 kJ.d-1, P < 0.001).
>   Furthermore, ST increased absolute RMR by 7% in both young (6302 +/-
>   1458 vs 6719 +/- 1617 kJ x d(-1), P < 0.01) and older (5614 +/- 916 vs
>   5999 +/- 973 kJ x d(-1), P < 0.05) subjects, with no significant
>   interaction between the two age groups. In contrast, there was a
>   significant gender x time interaction (P < 0.05) for absolute RMR with
>   men increasing RMR by 9% (6645 +/- 1073 vs 7237 +/- 1150 kJ x d(-1), P
>   < 0.001), whereas women showed no significant increase (5170 +/- 884
>   vs 5366 +/- 692 kJ x d(-1), P = 0.108). When RMR was adjusted for
>   fat-free mass (FFM) using ANCOVA, with all subjects pooled together,
>   there was still a significant increase in RMR with ST. Additionally,
>   there was still a gender effect (P < 0.05) and no significant age
>   effect (P = NS), with only the men still showing a significant
>   elevation in RMR. Moreover, EEPA and TEE estimated with a Tritrac
>   accelerometer and TEE estimated by the Stanford Seven-Day Physical
>   Activity Recall Questionnaire did not change in response to ST for any
>   group.

I think you can walk away with this by saying that men had a 7% increase.